# vue js удалить товар из корзины через 10 минут?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Проект на vue

есть задача, добавлять товар в корзину, со временем, по истечению которого, товар удаляется из корзины

товар в корзину добавляю в стор

```
    state.cart.push({
      id: product.id,
      name: product.name,
      path: product.path,
      image: product.image,
      price: product.price,
      old_price: product.old_price,
      created_at: new Date().getTime(), //текущая дата
      expiration_at: new Date().getTime() + 10000 текущая дата + 10 мин,
      quantity: 1
    })
```

как реализовать автоматическое удаление товара из корзины, если прошло 10 минути заказ не оформлен

Comment: Можно сделать `setInterval()` при запуске скрипта, который будет каждую минуту проверять наличие просроченных предметов в корзине

Comment: а можно по-подробнее, я не совсем понимаю принцип этой реализации

Comment: В хуке `mounted()` создаём `setInterval()` с интервалом в минуту, внутри проверяем все позиции товаров на срок годности, удаляем из корзины с вышедшим сроком годности. Чтобы удалить интервал вызываем `clearInterval()` в хуке `beforeUnmount()`. Подробнее об [интервалах](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval) и [хуках](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: а это в компоненте товара или в layout ?

Comment: В компоненте разметки. Т.к. Вам нужно проверять все товары и изменять state с этими товарами

Answer (score 0):

В хуке `mounted()` создаём `setInterval()` с интервалом в минуту, внутри проверяем все позиции товаров на срок годности, удаляем из корзины с вышедшим сроком годности. Чтобы удалить интервал вызываем `clearInterval()` в хуке `beforeUnmount()`. Подробнее об [интервалах](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval) и [хуках](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html). Возможно это не самый хороший и правильный способ, но он рабочий. Здесь идёт итерация массива с товарами, что плохо может сказаться на производительности.

Есть второй способ: скрывать товары, у которых истёк срок годности (прямо в компоненте проверяйте или в `v-for` с `v-if`), а перед тем как делать заказ - чистите эти товары.